# Undefined variable - why is it used?

Tags: julia, undefined

I am using Tanmay teaches Julia for beginners. I am working on the Caesar Cipher and there is one variable that is undefined. The variable is "filtered_characters" and I have no clue where it should go.

```
print("What offset would you like to shift by? ")
offset = parse(Int64, readline())

letters = [" "]
append!(letters, string.(collect('a':'z')))

user_input = read(open("document.txt"), String)
input_characters = string.(split(user_input, ""))
character_indices = map(x -> findfirst(y -> y == x, letters), filtered_characters)


function determine_new_index(x)
    x += offset
    if x <= length(letters) && x >= 1
        return x
    end
    if x > length(letters)
        return x - length(letters)
    end
    if x < 1
        return x + length(letters)
    end
end

character_indices = determine_new_index.(character_indices)

new_characters = map(x -> letters[x], character_indices)
new_string = join(new_characters, "")
encrypted_file = open("encrypted_document.txt", "w")
write(encrypted_file, new_string)
```

Can anyone help? I just started Julia and I've figured out the other snafus, but this one is a hard.

Gary

I tried using using it as an array but it came back as an error. I tried using circshift(letters, offset) but that did not answer it either.

Comment: Where is it you think you have defined `filtered_characters`? You use it in the map call, but it isn't defined anyway. Did you mean to use `input_characters` there?

Comment: I tried using `input_characters` but the error moved down to where it said invalid index - nothing of type Nothing for line 32 (`new_characters = map...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's meant to be

```
  filtered_characters = filter(in(letters), input_characters)
```

between the `input_characters =`  line and the `character_indices =`  line.

That works, but leaves out any characters in the input file that aren't in `a:z` (so punctuations, spaces, or capital letters are all ignored). And overall, the code here is a bit weirdly written (for eg. lots of things in the global scope, quite a roundabout way of achieving the goal, and the `map(x -> findfirst` part should most likely have been written using `indexin` instead).

Here's an alternate way of writing this:

```
function main(; infile = "document.txt", outfile = "encrypted_document.txt")
  print("What offset would you like to shift by? ")
  offset = parse(Int64, readline())

  open(infile) do input
    open(outfile; write = true) do output
      while !eof(input)
        ch = caesarcipher(read(input, Char), offset)
        write(output, ch)
      end
    end
  end
end

function caesarcipher(char, offset)
  if 'a' <= char <= 'z'
    return 'a' + (char - 'a' + offset) % 26
  elseif 'A' <= char <= 'Z'
    return 'A' + (char - 'A' + offset) % 26
  else
    return char
  end
end

main()
```

Comment: You're code works. First off, thank you!

Comment: Next, I read Tanmay Bakshi Teaches Julia. Unfortunately, this was not the fist program I had to fix, but it was the one that really did not make sense. I would make this as answered, but it says I need 15 points.